# If $f$ and $g$ are invertible and $f\circ g$ is defined, is $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In the proof for that any invertible functions $f$ and $g$ with $f \circ g$ defined, $(f\circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, it seems to me that there is an assumption that $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ is defined. I do not understand this and to illustrate I use what for me looks like a counter example:

$g = \{(a,1), (b,2)\}, \quad g^{-1} =\{(1, a), (2, b) \} $
$f =  \{(1,4), (2,5), (3,6) \} \quad f^{-1} = \{(4,1), (5,2), (6,3) \} $

Then $f \circ g$ is defined since Range of $g$ $\subset$ Domain of $f$
However, $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ is not defined since $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(6))$ is not defined.

How can it then be true that $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$?

Comment: $g$ is invertible if Dom$(g)=\{a,b\}$ and Ran$(g)=\{1,2\}$, but not invertible if Ran$(g)=\{1,2,3\}$ since it is not a bijection. A function is always defined with a domain and a range. Without giving the domain and the range, you cannot take the inverse of a function (you can't even define it).

Comment: For $f \circ g$ to be defined, it is required that $g:X \rightarrow Y$ and $f:Y \rightarrow Z$.  I.e., the range of $g$ and the domain of $f$ must be the same.

Comment: @EricTowers My book says that $g:X \rightarrow Y$ means that the function $g$ has the codomain $Y$, not the range $Y$. It then proceeds to state that the composition $f\circ g$ is defined if the codomain and domain of $g$ and $f$ are the same. Is this wrong then?

Comment: I once believed that people were careful about the difference between range and codomain.  I have subsequently learned that they are not.  For instance, your book tells you the thing I wrote using $\rightarrow$s, so tells you the thing about codomains.  But what you wrote in your Question uses the phrase "range of $g$".  Which of these two options do you believe?

Comment: @EricTowers When I say Range, I mean the Image of the function, the set of actual outputs from the function. With codomain, I mean the set of possible outputs of the function, not necessarily the set of actual outputs. So the thing that bothers me is that my book states that a composition is defined for two functions $g: X\rightarrow Y$ and $f: Y\rightarrow Z$, that is, the set of possible outputs of $g$ must be the domain of $f$. This constraint opens up for the scenario I described above, where the range of $g$ is a proper subset of the domain of $f$.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I realise that since an invertible function is one-one and onto, the codomain is the same as the range in this case. So in my example $f\circ g$ is not defined either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A composition $f\circ g$ is defined iff $g: A \rightarrow B$ and $f: B \rightarrow C$, that is, the codomain of $g$ is the domain of $f$. Since an invertible function is one-one and onto, in this case the codomain is the same as the range of the function $g$. Therefore in my example $f\circ g$ is not defined to begin with.

Comment: This is right, iff you use the definition of function to include codomain and domain. But I really hate this definition, much simpler to just define a function purely as it's graph like you did in your question.

Comment: Using the simpler definition, your function $f \circ g$ is defined, but $(f \circ g)^{-1}(6)$ is not so there is no problem.